# Bootstrap sass variables overriding

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I can't override bootstrap variables from my `main.scss` file

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$primary: green;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

I'm trying to override default value of bootstrap's scss variables, but it wasn't apply and all I see is the default color

Comment: Have you tired to move down your variable? So that you first import the bootstrap.scss then declarer  $primary: green;

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a mistake. Remove these lines:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

You don't need to import these because these are already present in the **bootstrap.scss**:-

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

So, your final code should be like this:-

```
$primary: green;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```